# How do I fix screen when I am inside screen running ptpython and its messed up due to autocomplete probably?

Tags: linux, terminal, python, gnu-screen, display

So, I am running this command
`os.system(f"screen -S Uploader -d -m bash -c 'bash uploader.sh 2>&1 | tee uploader_log'")`.

Uploader.sh in turns runs a python script that was displaying normally. However, it runs `from ptpython.repl import embed; embed(globals(), locals())` when it gets IndexError. So before error, it was displaying fine but it hit a error and is now displaying weirdly as you can see in the picture.

[image: Bad Display]

Normally, it displays it like this [image: normal embed]

Is there a way to fix it? I guess its related to ptpython autocomplete feature? I can execute os.system('touch test') and it gets executed fine from repl. Its just that its displaying is bugging me out.

As a side note, `screen -S test -d -m bash -c 'python3.12 -c "from ptpython.repl import embed; embed(globals(), locals())"'` is working properly.

However, `screen -S test -d -m bash -c 'bash test.sh 2>&1 | tee log'` is displaying weirdly when test.sh contains `python3.12 -c 'from ptpython.repl import embed; embed(globals(), locals())'`

Comment: Does `Ctrl+L` help?

Comment: I tried it already with no luck. You can reproduce my issue by creating a test.sh containing `python3.12 -c 'from ptpython.repl import embed; embed(globals(), locals())'` and running `screen -S test -d -m bash -c 'bash test.sh 2>&1 | tee log'`. Then screen -x test @terdon. I am also running it on VPS with no $DISPLAY but I enabled Xvfb, and exported $DISPLAY to :99. Not sure if that can play a role in this issue

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a try. Are you talking about the log file being displayed strangely, or is it the live terminal output? Your suggested command doesn't produce anything on the screen, on my machine. However, the log file contains a lot of windows line endings, which is odd, but almost certainly the source of your problems.

Comment: Yes, it's the `\r`, the Windows Line endings. If you run `dos2unix log` or `tr -d '\t' < log` you should get the expected output. The question is why this seems to be configured for Windows-style line endings by default even though it is installed on a Linux machine. I suspect it's a bug in ptpython.

Comment: I have raised issue and shared link of this question on ptpython github repo about this issue. Its probably related to bug in ptpython. Maybe the owners will probably answer do a bugfix or answer on how to fix it. tr -d '\r' seems to display the log better but i wanted a fix in the live terminal itself. Gotta wait for their reply on this issue.

Comment: I strongly urge you to open an proper issue or at least edit [the existing one](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/ptpython/issues/536). Don't expect the devs to come here and read the details, add the details and a full explanation including the steps to reproduce into the issue itself. That will make it easier for the devs to help you.

Comment: Thanks. Will do